# Stick element inside absolute positioned container

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, sticky

Considering an element **`".sticky-element"`** (*orange*) that is inside an absolute positioned container **`".tab"`** (*green, blue, fuchsia*).

I wish to make it "sticky", so when the the parent **`".container"`** (*grey*) scrolls, the **`".sticky-element"`** stays always on the top.

I've tried  without success getting the offset position of the sticky elements and control the "top" accordingly with the scroll position of the container. Is there any pure CSS solution? If not, how to accomplish this with JS?

---

**Here it is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ka1ros/pen/zYWQQKx) with the HTML/CSS of the concept.**

---

[image: scroll0]

[image: scroll1]

[image: scroll2]

Comment: You have multiple sticky boxes, so what do you want to happen it reaches the next one?

Comment: Sticky boxes should be bounded to the absolute container - they just "move" inside the absolute div, when this div is out of screen, so the sticky box should be

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if I got what you're looking for, but the orange headers stick to the top when scrolling. I had to move them outside of the containers you had them in so they would display like your photo and added a min-width and height to your sticky class. And finally, set a z-index value on the sticky element.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 50px;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.tab {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s width;
}

.tab:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background: orange;
  position: sticky;
  z-index:1;
}

.child-handler {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.group[groupid="1"] .child {
  background: green;
}

.group[groupid="2"] .child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
    
      <div class="sticky-element">Sticky 1</div>
      
      <div class="group" groupid="1">
        <div class="tab">
          
        </div>
        <div class="child-handler">
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="sticky-element">More Sticky</div>
      
      <div class="group" groupid="2">
        <div class="tab">
          
        </div>
        <div class="child-handler">
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Its almost there but the orange should stop being sticked on the end of a group. When a group is scrolled almost to the top, the position of the div should change to fixed (???). How can I calculate that moment and the subsequent negative top?

Comment: If you want the div to change from sticky to something else when the next sticky reaches it, you'll need to look into a javascript solution.  If all the stickys are the same size, then overlapping them shouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution of @Phaelax z I solve the problem with this approach:

```js
$.each($(".group"), function() {
  $(this).css("min-height", $(this).find(".child-handler").innerHeight());
});

function animate(el, width) {
  el.stop().animate({
    width: width
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    step: function(currentWidth) {
      const sticky = el.closest(".group").children(".sticky-element");
      const left = parseInt(sticky.css("left"));
      sticky.css("width", currentWidth - left);
    }
  });
}
$(".tab")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    animate($(this), "100%");
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    animate($(this), 20);
  });
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 50px;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-element {
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 0;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: orange;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tab-child-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tab {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tab-content {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-handler {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.group[groupid="1"] .child {
  background: green;
}

.group[groupid="2"] .child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="group" groupid="1">
        <div class="sticky-element">Sticky 1</div>
        <div class="tab-child-wrap">
          <div class="tab">
            <div class=".tab-content">Content</div>
          </div>
          <div class="child-handler">
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group" groupid="2">
        <div class="sticky-element">More Sticky</div>
        <div class="tab-child-wrap">
          <div class="tab">
            <div class=".tab-content">Content</div>
          </div>
          <div class="child-handler">
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```